# Aggregate window function and outer join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to solve the following question in a performance-oriented way. My current implementation involves ugly loops and is painfully slow.

Specifically, I have a table (transactions) of timestamped orders per customer for various items:

| timestamp | customer | item | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Joe | A | 100 |
| 2001 | Joe | A | 200 |
| 2001 | Doe | A | 100 |

Besides, I have a second table (valuations) showing prices for the items:

| timestamp | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | A | 1.1 |
| 2001 | A | 1.2 |
| 2002 | A | 1.3 |

Now, I would like to track the value (price*stock) of each customer's stock (cumulative volume) sampled according to the timestamp in the valuations table:

| timestamp | customer | item | stock | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Joe | A | 100 | 110 |
| 2001 | Joe | A | 300 | 360 |
| 2002 | Joe | A | 300 | 390 |
| 2001 | Doe | A | 100 | 120 |
| 2002 | Doe | A | 100 | 130 |

Essentially, this is going to be some form of (right) joining transactions and valuations. However, the catch here is that I would have to do one right join per (customer, item) combination. In other words, for every (customer, item) I would have to join the full set of timestamps.

My current (potentially pretty inefficient) solution loops across customers. For every customer, it creates the cumulative volume, right joins valuations and forward-fills (using the last function) columns coming from the transactions table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.last_func(anyelement, anyelement)
 RETURNS anyelement
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE STRICT
AS $function$
select $2;
$function$
;

   create or replace function last_func(anyelement, anyelement)
returns anyelement language sql immutable strict
as $$
    select $2;
$$;
    
select 
    valuations.timestamp,
    last(t.customer) over (partition by valuations.item order by valuations.timestamp) as customer,
    valuations.item,
    last(t.stock) over (partition by valuations.item order by valuations.timestamp) as stock,
    last(t.stock) over (partition by valuations.item order by valuations.timestamp) * valuations.price as value
from (select 
    timestamp,
    customer,
    item,
    volume as order_volume,
    sum(volume) over (partition by item order by item, timestamp) as stock
from 
    transactions
where customer = 'Joe') t
right join 
    valuations on t.timestamp = valuations.timestamp and t.item = valuations.item
```

This seems rather inefficient and becomes very slow for a large number of customers. Does anyone have an idea how to do that in one go? Would be great if you could help me out here.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: please enter desired output

Comment: you can find the desired output in the third table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion, since I can't test this on large amounts of data.

But what if you use a temporary table that contains all expected combinations of the customers and validations.

Then left join to customers to calculate the rolling sum.

**For example:**

> ```
> create temporary table tmp_customer_valuations (
>  timestamp int not null, 
>  item varchar(30) not null, 
>  customer varchar(30) not null, 
>  price decimal(10,1) not null
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into tmp_customer_valuations
> (timestamp, item, price, customer)
> select v.timestamp, v.item, v.price, c.customer
> from valuations v
> join (
>   select item, customer, min(timestamp) as min_timestamp
>   from transactions
>   group by item, customer 
> ) c
>   on c.item = v.item
>  and c.min_timestamp <= v.timestamp
> ```

> ```
> create index idx_tmp_customer_valuations
> on tmp_customer_valuations (timestamp, item)
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   tmp.timestamp
> , tmp.customer
> , tmp.item
> --, tr.volume as order_volume,
> , sum(coalesce(tr.volume, 0)) 
>      over (partition by tmp.item, tmp.customer 
>            order by tmp.timestamp) as stock
> , tmp.price * sum(coalesce(tr.volume, 0)) 
>      over (partition by tmp.item, tmp.customer 
>            order by tmp.timestamp) as value
> from tmp_customer_valuations tmp
> left join transactions tr
>   on tr.timestamp = tmp.timestamp 
>  and tr.item = tmp.item
>  and tr.customer = tmp.customer
> order by
>  tmp.customer desc,
>  tmp.item,
>  tmp.timestamp;
> ```

| timestamp | customer | item | stock | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Joe | A | 100 | 110.0 |
| 2001 | Joe | A | 300 | 360.0 |
| 2002 | Joe | A | 300 | 390.0 |
| 2001 | Doe | A | 100 | 120.0 |
| 2002 | Doe | A | 100 | 130.0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8112377f2d861c7307f3ef88bb6166f8)*

*(Btw, also verify if the tables could use an extra index)*

Comment: This seems to run pretty fast. But is there really a need for generating the temp table? Can't we just put tmp_customer_valuations directly into the final query and postgres is going to sort out whether it wants to create an intermediate index?

Comment: Not sure, but you can try putting the query of the insert in a CTE or sub-query, and verify how it performs. If it's fine, then all the better I guess.

Comment: Just tried that, seems to work pretty well: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d11cd860bfc26041ffc758898f4a5cae

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good case for lateral join. This doesn't assume that the timestamps will be identical. I'm guessing that the general case will potentially have none or even multiple transactions between valuations. (I'm not even sure that you need an outer join.)

```
select v.*, stock * price
from valuations v left join lateral (
    select distinct on (customer) customer,
        sum(volume) over (partition by customer, item order by timestamp) as stock
    from transactions t
    where t.item = v.item and t.timestamp <= v.timestamp
    order by customer, timestamp desc
) t on true
order by customer, timestamp
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=af82f52655dfc55029e430b7933cd899